# Direct access to Prometheus Database

Tags: prometheus

Prometheus is great database ([top10 time series databases](https://blog.outlyer.com/top10-open-source-time-series-databases#Prometheus)), but the only way i found to manipulate its data was the [REST API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/).

Is there more direct way to access Prometheus database? Because the REST API has only partially functional. For example, it is not possible to insert new data directly into the database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus is primarily a monitoring system, so there is no direct database access as that is not required for monitoring. You can build your own on top of its [tsdb](https://github.com/prometheus/tsdb).

Comment: I plan to setup a ML pipeline on the data exposed from various sources to Prometheus. I cant find a direct way to access the data. (It is immutable data and hence fits my case). Can you please elaborate a little bit on your comment to build on top of tsdb?